# Include all the days when using limit?

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, time-series

I want want to get all rows from 1st August to 31 August but limit to 1500 rows, however, it must include all the possible days from 1 to 31. So from each day I expected around 48 rows.

How is that possible with SQL Query?

I have tried this SQL query but it wont include all the days because I am using `limit`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
      WHERE `submit` >= '2014-08-01' AND  `submit` <=  '2014-08-31' 
order by `submit`
      LIMIT 1500
```

Update:

It should get all the possible days from 1 to 31, if any days does not have enough rows - then include the remaining rows from any days. If there is no record on the 7th Aug for example, then any other days should include more rows.

Update2:

Let say `submit >= '2014-08-01' AND  submit <=  '2014-08-31'` there are 3000 rows but I only want 1000 rows (if possible) from 01 to 31.

Each day should have approx 32 rows.

For example

Aug 01 have 32 rows

Aug 02 have 32 rows

Aug 03 only 0 rows

Aug 04 only 0 rows

Aug 05 have 32 rows

to

Aug 31 have 32 rows

Comment: Your present query potentially omits rows from the end of the month, if there are more than 1500 rows for the month. Which rows should be omitted instead so that you get at least one row for each day of the month? What should happen if the table contains no rows for a particular day of the month? Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: So... In other words: you want to get for example 1600 rows, but max 1500? Its a paradox. Try to grab all 50 matches but only 25. Impossible

Comment: @OllieJones I have updated the question, hopefully it make sense

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. What rows should be omitted if there are too many rows? You've ruled out omitting the rows from the end of the month. What rows should be omitted instead? Should we include at least one row from each day, and then omit whatever other rows we want?

Comment: @OllieJones I have updated again, sorry if doesn't make sense

Comment: For the purposes of simplifying the question, maybe you could have between 0 and 5 results per day, for which you want to return a minimum of 1 per day up to a maximum of 50 rows. That's where I'd start from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a troublesome requirement, because it calls for the unpredictable omission of data under unpredictable circumstances. This is the kind of thing that gives auditors bad dreams (not to mention programmers). It may help you to figure out what exactly you are trying to do with this result set, and tighten up your requirement.

Assuming your table has an autoincrementing unique `id` column, here's a query that will retrieve the last row from the table for each date.

```
        SELECT 0 AS priority, t.* FROM table1 AS t
         WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE(submit))
```

You can then do this to get the remaining rows:

```
        SELECT 1 AS priority, t.* FROM table1 AS t
         WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE(submit))
```

You can take the union of these, sort them, and limit them.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 0 AS priority, t.* FROM table1 AS t
         WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE(submit))
  UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 AS priority, t.* FROM table1 AS t
         WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE(submit))
         ) AS results
  ORDER BY priority, submit
  LIMIT 1500
```

This will give you at least one row from each `submit` date, and then the rest of the rows, but never more than 1500. It makes no attempt to balance the number of rows from each date, however.

Comment: Don't I need to include  `WHERE `submit` >= '2014-08-01' AND `submit` <= '2014-08-31' ` ?

Comment: This SQL query is hanging the server forever.

Comment: Yes, you should include the date-selection logic (in the `SELECT MAX(id)` subqueries). I didn't include it because I was hoping to give you a conceptual way to address your requirement. As far as performance goes, that's probably a different question. When you ask it, don't forget to include your table and index definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. The data table...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,dt DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (dt) VALUES
('2014-07-28'),
('2014-07-29'),
('2014-08-01'),
('2014-08-01'),
('2014-08-02'),
('2014-08-03'),
('2014-08-05'),
('2014-08-05'),
('2014-08-05'),
('2014-08-05'),
('2014-08-07'),
('2014-08-07'),
('2014-08-09'),
('2014-08-10'),
('2014-08-10'),
('2014-08-10'),
('2014-08-11'),
('2014-08-13'),
('2014-08-13'),
('2014-08-13'),
('2014-08-13'),
('2014-08-13'),
('2014-08-13'),
('2014-08-14'),
('2014-08-14'),
('2014-08-15'),
('2014-08-17'),
('2014-08-17'),
('2014-08-18'),
('2014-08-18'),
('2014-08-18'),
('2014-08-19'),
('2014-08-19'),
('2014-08-21'),
('2014-08-21'),
('2014-08-21'),
('2014-08-21'),
('2014-08-22'),
('2014-08-23'),
('2014-08-25'),
('2014-08-25'),
('2014-08-26'),
('2014-08-26'),
('2014-08-26'),
('2014-08-27'),
('2014-08-28'),
('2014-08-29'),
('2014-08-29'),
('2014-08-29'),
('2014-08-29'),
('2014-08-29'),
('2014-08-30'),
('2014-08-31'),
('2014-08-31');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------------+
| id | dt         |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2014-07-28 |
|  2 | 2014-07-29 |
|  3 | 2014-08-01 |
|  4 | 2014-08-01 |
|  5 | 2014-08-02 |
|  6 | 2014-08-03 |
|  7 | 2014-08-05 |
|  8 | 2014-08-05 |
|  9 | 2014-08-05 |
| 10 | 2014-08-05 |
| 11 | 2014-08-07 |
| 12 | 2014-08-07 |
| 13 | 2014-08-09 |
| 14 | 2014-08-10 |
| 15 | 2014-08-10 |
| 16 | 2014-08-10 |
...
...
| 44 | 2014-08-26 |
| 45 | 2014-08-27 |
| 46 | 2014-08-28 |
| 47 | 2014-08-29 |
| 48 | 2014-08-29 |
| 49 | 2014-08-29 |
| 50 | 2014-08-29 |
| 51 | 2014-08-29 |
| 52 | 2014-08-30 |
| 53 | 2014-08-31 |
| 54 | 2014-08-31 |
+----+------------+
```

Step 2. A calendar utility table holding all conceivable dates... (there are other ways of doing this, but - unusually - this problem requires that this is done here, in MySQL, rather than in post-processing)

```
SELECT *
  FROM calendar
 WHERE dt BETWEEN '2014-07-28' AND '2014-09-02';
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2014-07-28 |
| 2014-07-29 |
| 2014-07-30 |
| 2014-07-31 |
| 2014-08-01 |
| 2014-08-02 |
| 2014-08-03 |
| 2014-08-04 |
| 2014-08-05 |
| 2014-08-06 |
| 2014-08-07 |
| 2014-08-08 |
| 2014-08-09 |
| 2014-08-10 |
| 2014-08-11 |
| 2014-08-12 |
| 2014-08-13 |
| 2014-08-14 |
| 2014-08-15 |
| 2014-08-16 |
| 2014-08-17 |
| 2014-08-18 |
| 2014-08-19 |
| 2014-08-20 |
| 2014-08-21 |
| 2014-08-22 |
| 2014-08-23 |
| 2014-08-24 |
| 2014-08-25 |
| 2014-08-26 |
| 2014-08-27 |
| 2014-08-28 |
| 2014-08-29 |
| 2014-08-30 |
| 2014-08-31 |
| 2014-09-01 |
| 2014-09-02 |
+------------+
37 rows in set
```

Step 3. The query (guaranteeing at least one result per day and no more than 50 results overall)

```
SELECT dt FROM 
(
SELECT a.dt
     , COALESCE(rank,0)
  FROM calendar a
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.dt,COUNT(*) rank
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.dt = x.dt 
          AND y.id <= x.id
        GROUP   
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.dt = a.dt
 WHERE a.dt BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'
 ORDER 
    BY rank,dt
 LIMIT 50
 )n
 ORDER BY dt; 
 +------------+
 | dt         |
 +------------+
 | 2014-08-01 |
 | 2014-08-01 |
 | 2014-08-02 |
 | 2014-08-03 |
 | 2014-08-04 |
 | 2014-08-05 |
 | 2014-08-05 |
 | 2014-08-05 |
 | 2014-08-06 |
 | 2014-08-07 |
 | 2014-08-07 |
 | 2014-08-08 |
 | 2014-08-09 |
 | 2014-08-10 |
 | 2014-08-10 |
 | 2014-08-10 |
 | 2014-08-11 |
 | 2014-08-12 |
 | 2014-08-13 |
 | 2014-08-13 |
 | 2014-08-13 |
 | 2014-08-14 |
 | 2014-08-14 |
 | 2014-08-15 |
 | 2014-08-16 |
 | 2014-08-17 |
 | 2014-08-17 |
 | 2014-08-18 |
 | 2014-08-18 |
 | 2014-08-18 |
 | 2014-08-19 |
 | 2014-08-19 |
 | 2014-08-20 |
 | 2014-08-21 |
 | 2014-08-21 |
 | 2014-08-21 |
 | 2014-08-22 |
 | 2014-08-23 |
 | 2014-08-24 |
 | 2014-08-25 |
 | 2014-08-25 |
 | 2014-08-26 |
 | 2014-08-26 |
 | 2014-08-27 |
 | 2014-08-28 |
 | 2014-08-29 |
 | 2014-08-29 |
 | 2014-08-30 |
 | 2014-08-31 |
 | 2014-08-31 |
 +------------+
 50 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something crazy like this perhaps?

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table1 
      WHERE `submit` = '2014-08-01'
        LIMIT 48
    UNION SELECT * FROM table1 
      WHERE `submit` = '2014-08-02'
        LIMIT 48
    UNION SELECT * FROM table1 
      WHERE `submit` = '2014-08-03'
        LIMIT 48
    UNION SELECT * FROM table1 
      WHERE `submit` = '2014-08-04'
        LIMIT 48
    etc...
    )
  UNION SELECT * FROM Table1 
      WHERE `submit` >= '2014-08-01' AND `submit` <= '2014-08-31'
  )
order by `submit`
  LIMIT 1500
```